# Web accessibility - alt tag

Tags: html

I need to put my website completely clean, with no accessibility errors.
I found this error: "Each A tag must contain text or an IMG with an ALT attribute" in this line:

```
<a href="#" class="alert_close"></a>
```

So I put the line like this:

```
<a alt="phpbb_alert" href="#" class="alert_close"></a>
```

But, I still have the same error and I have another one: "Attribute 'alt' not allowed on element"

How can I solve this problem, please?

Comment: Can you post the line of code having error?

Comment: `alt` is not a valid attribute for `<a>`. It is for `<img>` tags.

Comment: It clearly says "... text OR an IMG with an ALT".   It says to add the alt to an `img`, not to the `a`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead, you want your `a` link to either contain text like this:

```
<a href="#">click me</a>
```

or to contain an image with a supporting alt tag like this:

```
<a href="#"><img src="/path/to/image.jpg" alt="alternative text here"></a>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I know that I make a really stupid question, but i'm a iniciante in acessibility web